# Rotate an image while it is being used

Tags: java, image, rotation, awt

I am creating a car game and I want to rotate my car ( Image ) when I'm using the car but I don't know how. I've tried a few things that don't work. Here is what I have:

```
g2d.drawImage(DEFAULT_CAR_SKIN, DEFAULT_BOX.x, DEFAULT_BOX.y, null);

DEFAULT_BOX.setLocation(DEFAULT_BOX.x + 1, DEFAULT_BOX.y);

if (Game.rotateFront == true) {
  AffineTransform identity = new AffineTransform();

  AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
  trans.setTransform(identity);
  trans.rotate(Math.toRadians(Game.Angle));
  g2d.drawImage(DEFAULT_CAR_SKIN, trans, this);
}
```

But this code draws a new image but with the characteristics that I want.

Comment: *"..but with the characteristics that I want."* unless you actually meant *"..but **not** with the characteristics that I want."* that statement makes no sense.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).